# Karate; Counting # of K:V pairs within an object in a json array

Tags: automated-tests, karate

For debugging purposes before writing out tests, I am looking to get the number of key:value pairs within the one object in the array.
Right now, I have this:

```
"items": [
   {
      "id": "6b0051ad-721d-blah-blah-4dab9cf39ff4",
      "external_id": "blahvekmce",
      "filename": "foo-text_field-XYGLVU",
      "created_date": "2019-02-11T04:10:31Z",
      "last_update_date": "2019-02-11T04:10:31Z",
      "file_upload_date": "2019-02-11T04:10:31Z",
      "deleted_date": null,
      "released_and_not_expired": true,
      "asset_properties": null,
      "file_properties": null,
      "thumbnails": null,
      "embeds": null
    }
  ]
```

When I write out:
`* print response.items.length // returns 1`

When I write out:
`* print response.items[0].length` it doesn't return anything

Any thoughts on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, but this should work, plus you see how to get the keys as well:

```
* def keys = []
* eval karate.forEach(response.items[0], function(x){ keys.add(x) })
* def count = keys.length
* match count == 12
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Comment: how would I pull `eval karate.forEach(response.items[0], function(x){ keys.add(x) })` out into the "Background" so I can reuse it for other scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Karate now provides `karate.sizeOf()` API to get count of an object.

```
* def object = { a: 1, b: 'hello' }
* def count = karate.sizeOf(object)
* match count == 2
```

Ref: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#the-karate-object

Answer (score -1):

```
count = 0
for (var v in response.items[0]) {
  count = count + 1;
}
print(count)
```

Comment: It would help readers (particularly learner)  if you would add further explanation to your to assist readers. Code only answers are considered impolite.